# recalc function not firing as described

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a recalc function on one of my client scripts that's deployed on Sales Orders. By definition, the recalc client event should only fire "after a sublist change, but only if the sublist change causes the total to change"; however, I've found that this is not the case. Simply clicking on a line item and then clicking the blue "OK" button is causing my recalc function to fire. Simply selecting an item and subsequently clicking "OK" does not cause any totals to change, thus it shouldn't be causing the recalc function to fire, correct? Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: I think you've found an undocumented "feature". It can be all too commonplace within the NetSuite API. To accommodate this, you might do some manual pre-checks in your function to avoid firing in these "OK" cases.

Comment: I've found the same thing.  I almost think they meant the sentence to read '...but only if the sublist change _could_ cause the total to change'.   Looking for a way to validate the change as @TonyH suggest, or moving the execution to a different event type might be the best options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are describing is intended by NetSuite - their "change" and your "change" don't necessarily mean the same thing. Even though you didn't necessarily change anything on the line, NS's UI is dumb to that and knows that you *could have*, so they recalc anyway.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way for you to get around this.

I assume you have a script running on recalc that takes too long and you'd like to speed things up, so perhaps there's a way to look at that script instead and refactor it to perform better?

Comment: I actually have a custom shipping calculator, so I've written my recalc function to clear the shipping cost if a line item changes. Instead, I have users clearing out the shipping cost when they just look at a note as a line item (for example). I have other functions that clear out the shipping cost too (like when the shipping method), but I was depending on the recalc to fire correctly when a line item changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just checking if the line item changes. You can use a line init function that stores the existing line item id in global variable.  Then on validate line, get the line item and check it against the global variable.